# Constraints for continuous path within graph with at least one obligatory node in path

Tags: optimization, linear-programming

I am trying to solve linear problem in IBM Cplex. Problem is a complicated version of cheapest path problem. For a given graph find best (cheapest) path between all pairs and go through at least one node from provided list. I solved basic version (without obligatory nodes) with node-link representation. For most cases following constrain was good enough:

sum ( obligatoryNode in obligatoryNodes, a in neighbourOut[obligatoryNode] ) x[<a, obligatoryNode>][d] >= 1;

However I encountered cases when this is not enough and I got additional not connected link just to fulfil that constrains.

**What is mathematical formula that ensure that founded path is continuous?**

My model from cplex https://pastebin.com/vJXCvggt

Comment: One way of dealing with this constraint is to compute the shortest path from vertices to the given node, and then from the given node to the vertices. Then just merge the paths.

Comment: This is not possible to implement in cplex with pure mathematical modelling approach. I can only add constraints